# Can you make a speaker out of steel or other metals?

Tags: sound

Can you make a speaker out of steel or other metals?

I'm thinking about this because on phones there needs to be holes for sound to exit but that also is an entry point for water to enter the phone and damage the electronics.

So with metal speakers they could be outside the shell and be more water proof or water resistant.

Comment: Waterproof earbuds and the phone in a waterproof container.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. No, it's not generally a good idea.

Generally speaking, you value three characteristics in a loudspeaker cone:

1. Maximum rigidity
2. Minimum mass
3. Minimum resonance

Just as a general rule, metals tend to do well on rigidity, but poorly on mass and even worse on resonance.

By far the most common material for loudspeakers (especially larger ones) is paper. Paper provides an excellent mix of rigidity, light weight, and sem-decent damping (much better that most metals anyway). Its Achilles heel is exactly what you've identified though: you have to keep it dry to work well. Even high humidity in the air can affect it.

For slightly higher-tech loudspeakers, you see more plastic (especially Polypropylene). Compared to paper, this generally loses some rigidity, but does much better at damping resonance. More relevantly to the question at hand, most plastic is quite waterproof.

At the high end, you get a lot of the "usual suspect" composites: carbon fiber, Kevlar, Aramid, along with a few that aren't so common (e.g., many high-end Tweeters use silk diaphragms/cones/domes).

For a cell phone, my first choice would be a plastic like Polypropylene. It has good damping and low mass, and cell phones use small enough speakers that rigidity isn't likely to be a major issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you make a speaker out of steel or other metals?

Certainly, the old handpiece-hangs-from-hook telephones had a steel diaphragm next to a magnet
as their sound-generator.   They sounded awful, though, and weren't
very  loud.

Any attempt to make a slender phone with a steel diaphragm speaker, will likely fail because steel CAN be bent  if  it's thin, and cannot
be thick and still do a good job of displacing air to  make sound.
Those old telephones could handle voice, but not music.

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase IP67-rated (1m of water for one hour) speakers off the shelf. They generally use a plastic membrane for the diaphram, such as polyester, polypropylene or polyetherimide.

Cones are sometimes made from rigid aluminum.

I'm not sure what advantage you'd glean from making the flexible part metal over plastic or silicone-- it's probably possible with a very thin appropriately shaped metal since many compressors diaphrams are made from metal.